# Looking for a Static Blog Generator

Tags: windows, open-source, static-site-generator

I want to build my own personal portfolio with a blog attached. So I am looking for a static blog generator where:

- The static generator is built with JavaScript. This is so that if I ever need extra functionality I can fork it, develop a plugin etc.
- Posts for the blog portion of the site can be generated using Markdown
- You can simply change the template language be it Jade, EJS etc.
- There is multilingual support
- You can easily change the edit the theme via HTML, CSS (SASS/LESS)
- It can run on Windows
- It is open source

Comment: [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) can do that, but it isn't written in JavaScript (it's written in Ruby)

Comment: I have looked at Jekyll before but if I want to extend any functionality via plugins, I'd have to use Ruby. I'd rather avoid that and use JavaScript.

Comment: A search on npm turns up a bunch of promising options: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=static%20site%20generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a static generator that has all the requirements I'm looking for.
It is called [Hexo](https://hexo.io/).

It's built with JavaScript and seems to be very active too.

I shall be going with this.